# Non English character not showing properly after reading from cmd in Citrix

Tags: c#, character-encoding, citrix

I am trying to run a command in cmd and read the result, where the result involves some Swedish and Finnish character by the below mentioned code. Now the code results ok when it is run on physical machine
possibly this StandardOutputCoding logic handle those character successfully. However when I am running it on an Citrix machine, it is not working. Even querying Textinfo.OEMPageCode does not show anything where as in physical machine it returns int value. I believe this piece of code (Textinfo.OEMPageCode) is not working in citrix that's why all those special character do not show properly. Can anyone please help how to solve this. Thanks in advance.

```
        string userName = environment.username;
        string fullName = "\"Full Name\"";

        command = String.Format("net user {0} /domain | findstr /C:{1}", userName, fullName);

        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            procStartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage);
            proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
            proc.Start();
            userFullName = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            userFullName = userFullName.Replace("Full Name", "").Trim();
            }
```

Comment: You mean non-latin? - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_alphabet

Comment: Hi, Sorry I dont know whether they are non-latin or not. I am actually looking to work with these kind of character.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1. Thanks

Comment: Try `procStartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(65001);`

Comment: Hi @JosefZ..its not working. Like I mentioned earlier, this getencoding is working on physical machine. I think it is somehow getting error because of Citrix environment. Not sure though. Thanks for the feedback